# How to convert oracle to_timestamp to sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to convert Oracle

`to_timestamp(coloum_name,'DD-MM-YYYY')` to sql

required output : `24-APR-17 12.00.00.000000000 PM`

Comment: Which SQL? ANSI SQL, or perhaps SQL Server type SQL?

Comment: microsoft SQL 2016 @jarlh

Comment: Where are you starting from? Do you have a variable, a table, ... ? And what do you need to get? Populate some variable? print something? make a select query?

Comment: i need to make a select query @Aleksej

Comment: Ok, so I assume that you have a table with some data; please post the table structure of this table. Also, what should the result type be? a varchar2?

Comment: my required out put is 24-APR-17 12.00.00.000000000 PM , i don't have the table structure.

Comment: You have to build a query, but you don't know the table from which you have do get data? As far as we know, your table could have a date stored as timestamp, varchar2, number, ... Also, this means that you need a varchar2 output, with the date value written in that format?

Comment: yes , my out date format must be as i mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it has an very searchable title, and there's no accepted answer.

The TO_TIMESTAMP function converts text representations of dates to a standard date/time format. From your question, it sounds like you have dates stored as characters in the format 'DD-MM-YYYY', but you want SQL Server DATETIME2(7) (based on the number of decimals in the seconds) as your output. It also seems you want the default time to be noon, rather than midnight, since your sample output shows 12:00 PM, not AM.

Using CONVERT with style 103 will change the European styled date to a DATETIME2(7), as shown below. But then you'll need to do a DATEADD to move from midnight (which will be the default value) to noon, which is twelve hours later.

```
DECLARE @DateSample NVARCHAR(10) = '17-04-2017';

SELECT CONVERT( DATETIME2(7), @DateSample, 103 );

--Results
--2017-04-17 00:00:00.0000000

SELECT DATEADD( HOUR, 12, CONVERT( DATETIME2(7), @DateSample, 103 ));

--Results
--2017-04-17 12:00:00.0000000
```

The SQL Server default is 24 hour time, so if you absolutely must switch to AM/PM designators, you'll have to convert it back to a string, which seems to be the opposite of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to convert a `date`/`timestamp` into `varchar2` in Oracle with the format you want

```
select to_char(yourColumn, 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF9 PM')
from yourTable
```

Comment: to_char is an oracle function, i wanted in MS SQL

Comment: I asked if you needed "a varchar2 output" and you said "yes", so I gave a solution for Oracle. Why did you answer that way if you needed something different?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'dd-MMM-yyyy h.mm.ss.fffffff tt')